# Proof verification: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1$ as groups without the first isomorphism theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

The lecture notes I'm working through assert that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1$ as groups via the map $f(t) = \exp(2 \pi i t)$, but it does so before introducing the first isomorphism theorem. I think it's easiest to use this theorem, but I'm trying nonetheless to prove directly that this is an isomorphism.

The one thing I'm not fully certain about is whether I need to check this map is well-defined. $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, in these notes, is defined as the set $[0,1)$ with addition mod $1$, rather than as a collection of equivalence classes. I think, with this definition, it isn't necessary to check well-definedness, but I do need to be mindful of whether a sum $x+y$ of elements in $[0,1)$ exceeds $1$ when regarded as a sum in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm going to denote addition mod $1$ with $+_{1}$. Here is my attempt at a proof.

> Define $f: \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to S^1$ by $f(t) = \exp(2 \pi i t)$. We check first that $f$ is a homomorphism. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = [0,1)$. If $x + y > 1$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then we have
> \begin{align*} 
> f(x+_{1} y) & = f(x + y - 1) \\
> & = \exp(2\pi i (x + y - 1) \\
> & = \exp(2 \pi i x + 2 \pi i y - 2\pi i ) \\
> & = \exp(2 \pi i x) \exp(2 \pi i y) \exp(- 2 \pi i) \\
> & = f(x) f(y) \cdot 1 \\
> & = f(x) f(y).
> \end{align*}
> Now we check that $f$ is bijective. For injectivity, it suffices to show that $\mathrm{ker}(f) = 0$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> x \in \mathrm{ker}(f) & \iff f(x) = 1 \\
> & \iff \exp(2\pi i x) = 1 \\
> & \iff \cos (2\pi x) + i \sin (2\pi x) = 1 + 0i \\
> & \iff \sin (2\pi x) = 0 \\
> & \iff x = 0.
> \end{align*}
> The last line implies that $x$ is an integer, but $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ implies that $x \in [0,1)$, so I believe that means that the only option is $x = 0$, so the kernel of $f$ is trivial. Next we show that $f$ is surjective. Let $z \in S^1$, so $z = e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

I'm having trouble finishing the proof of surjectivity. I tried expanding out both sides using Euler's formula, but I don't know which value of $t$ equates $e^{i \theta} = ^{2\pi i t}$.

Another approach I considered was showing that $f$ admits an inverse, but I can't figure out what this inverse is. The log function doesn't work because $\log(\exp(2\pi i t) = 2\pi i t$ which is not $t$.

Comment: As $\theta$ is in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, $t := \frac1{2\pi}\theta$ is in the interval $[0,1)$ and $f(t) = e^{2\pi ti} = e^{\theta i} = z$.

Comment: @azif00 Very helpful, thank you. Was there anything to my thought to supply an inverse, or does that not hold over $\mathbb{C}$?